# installing on existing devices

Tags: system-installation, ubuntu-touch

Can I install your system on my mobile and/or tablet? and how?? I think it will be more better if you can provide this features it will help to spread the system in short time

thanks

Answer (score 0):

It depends which tablet/phone you have, there is a version of Ubuntu called ubuntu touch, designed for phones and tablets, however it only works on some hardware. It is also still in beta, so make not work exactly as expected. For installation instructions see here (to do this install you need a computer running ubuntu): https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Install